# Dynamically Resizing Flash Object to Fill Window

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache-flex, flash

I have a Flash/Flex object (Flashlight-VNC), which I would like to dynamically resize to fit the entire window after pressing a button in the Flex app. This would preferably happen without restarting the Flex app (and therefore the VNC session). I would just use the built-in Flash fullscreen mode, however Adobe's somewhat silly security restrictions prevent keyboard input while in fullscreen mode.

How exactly can I do this? I'm already using SWFObject to embed the SWF, if that helps. I am open to any solution utilizing ActionScript, JavaScript, or both, however I am not all too familiar with ActionScript or Flex, and the AS-based solutions I have found involve extending a "Sprite" object to add resize functionality, which Flashlight-VNC does not seem to use.

I see that there is a very similar question already posted on this site, however the accepted answer points to one dead link and another link that does not answer my question (my goal is to resize the object on command, not from when the page loads).

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried searching for the dead link and using google cache?

Comment: No keyboard input while in fullscreen mode sounds suspect to me; be sure to file a bug with that. bogs.adobe.com

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, that's expected behavior for Flash full screen mode.  Only certain limited keys are available, space and arrows.  It's a security precaution (a very extreme one IMO).

Comment: Yeah, the fullscreen thing is on purpose. Nathan, I did try that, but it was not available on Google's cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really isn't related to flash. It's more about HTML DOM manipulation.  You want to make sure your Flash SWF is set to use 100%/100% and then when you want to trigger "full screen" mode change the html container to be placed in the top-left-most corner and have a width/height of 100% of screen.

You'll still have the browser's toolbars and tabs and address bar, but if you want keyboard input there aren't many options.